# How to print copy number using system.drawing.printing.printdocument vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

For instance, I have a single label to print like below example, now if I want to make 3 copies of it, How can I print the copy number somewhere in the label I'm printing?

Sample code:

```
Private Sub btnPrintProcLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrintProcLabel.Click
        If ValidateData() Then
            AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintProcLabel

            Try
                PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = SinglePrinter.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
                PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.Copies = CInt(txtCopies.Text)
                PrintDocument1.Print()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

Public Sub PrintProcLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim br As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        Dim pn As Pen = New Pen(br)

        g.DrawString(Today.Month & "/" & Today.Day & "/" & Today.Year, Arial, br, 250, 3)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.Copies = CInt(txtCopies.Text)
```

That tells the printer driver to generate the copies, they will all be identical.  If you want to number them then you'll need to create the "copies" yourself.  They are not really copies anymore since they'll all be slightly different.  Just call the Print() method repeatedly, using a counter whose value you DrawString() in your PrintPage event handler.

Comment: yes, I was thinking in iterate as many times as specified in `txtCopies.Text` so I can have the specific copy number everytime. I think there is no other way to do this.